# Save packages and ppa list since system install

Tags: installation, package-management, ppa

I'm going to change from 32 to 64 bit, there's anyway I can save a list of added ppa's and installed packages since first boot? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only do this:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* > savedppa.list
```

Then save your savedppa.list and place it on the new system:

```
sudo cp savedppa.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo apt-get update
```